# JSF selectCheckBoxMenu not working properly in IE

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I am facing an issue with my jsf application while running it on IE.

The `selectcheckboxmenu` on jsf behaves faulty and has the checkboxes of the menu items shifted below the items, The checkboxes are still there. Below is the screenshot of what i am facing : 
[image: Image and video hosting by TinyPic]

[IMG]http://i43.tinypic.com/8yb976.jpg[/IMG]

the code for the selectcheckboxmenu is given below :

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{formBean.selectedMovies}" label="Movies"
    filter="true" filterText="Filter" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
    panelStyle="width:220px">
    <f:selectItems value="#{formBean.movies}" />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

Please kindly tell me where am I going wrong and what is the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is compatibility problem with IE. 
Primefaces runs good on IE9 compatibility.
And your check box is not working beacause of this.

I had gone through the same issues. So you have to set the Compatibility view by using the life cycle of jsf

```
public class UACompatibleHeaderPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {
@Override
public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent arg0){}

@Override
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event){
    final FacesContext facesContext = event.getFacesContext();
    final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    response.addHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge");
}

@Override
public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
     return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
}
}
```

And in your Faces-config.xml just place the class with the packagename

```
<lifecycle>
   <phase-listener>
     com.jsf.listener.UACompatibleHeaderPhaseListener
   </phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

Comment: well thanks for help it is working fine in IE9. Is there any way we can make it work fine on IE 7 & 8 ??

Comment: When testing in IE7 and IE8, do you absolutely _must_ test with nothing later IE8. If that means you have to set up a virtual machine, then do it. IE9 and IE10's compatibility mode is absolutely _awful_ and doesn't properly emulate the old environments at all. In my experience, IE8 did properly emulate IE7 though.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with css property 'vertical-align',

```
div.ui-selectcheckboxmenu.ui-widget{
width: 100% !important;
}
div.ui-widget-header.ui-corner-all.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-header.ui-helper-clearfix{
padding: 3px !important;

}
input.ui-inputfield.ui-inputtext.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all{

width: 90% !important;

}
div.ui-chkbox-box.ui-widget.ui-corner-all{
vertical-align: top !important;
margin-top: 3px !important;
}
div.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-filter-container{
width:75% !important;
vertical-align: top !important;
margin-left: 2px !important;
}
```

Tested on firefox, chrome and ie9.