# Primefaces showcase examples not properly working on IE 10?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I was debugging some stuff on my site that was problematic in IE but working fine in chrome/firefox & then I checked out primefaces showcase on the same browser(IE10), & to my surprise most of the ajax(may be all) stuff like p:autocomplete, p:ajax etc isn't working for me.

I'm sure there must be something wrong at my end as surely it cant be that it doesn't work in IE. But actually what could be wrong at my end. I'm just browsing & playing with the [live PF showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompleteBasic.jsf), on IE 10 but ajax stuff doesn't seem to work. 
For e.g. while playing with [autocomplete component in the showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompleteBasic.jsf) in IE10, HTTP calls are made but responses are always empty & the autocomplete don't return any responses as suggestions list as it does on other browsers like chrome/firefox.

Does anyone have any idea what may be wrong ??

Comment: You could try posting this in PrimeFaces forum.

Comment: yep, already did that!

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on your browser settings. I can browse the showcase using IE10 and it looks ok (including autocomplete showcase). However, if I browse it in Compatibility View (that is, if I click the icon on the right side of the address bar), autocomplete showcase behaves just as you described.

I've experienced some issues with Primefaces and IE8. However, in IE9 and IE10 everything seems to work much better.

Comment: are you able to get suggestions in IE when you type something in p:autocomplete component's input field ? (I'm experiencing these issue in standard as well as compatibility mode.)

Comment: Yeah. Primefaces components don't properly work with IE8, but with some settings we can overcome this issue. If you click `comptibility mode` means it will go back `IE8 or Ie7 standards`,that will cause Issues

Comment: The components are rendered properly for me too, but the ajax features don't work as expected. Like autocomplete cannot fetch suggestions although an HTTP request is sent.

Comment: user01 - yes, as long as I don't switch to "Compatibility View", all showcase examples of p:autocomplete work perfectly fine. When I type something, the list with suggestion is displayed and it changes with every keystroke.

Comment: that's strange that it doesnt work for me, being the same IE version. Any other issue in the IE settings that you could think of, that may be the culprit?

Comment: It also stops working when I switch security level to "High". With "Medium" it works alright. Generally, with default settings it just works. You can try resetting your settings to default and see what happens.

Comment: I just resetted my IE10 completely but nothing changed :(  I'm using IE 10.0.9200.16721 on Win8

Comment: (+1) for the information with "Compatibility View". I can confirm that turning "Compatibility View" on is causing a lot of problems. If it is turned of, everything works fine for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the compatibility not being set in IE browser.
How ever things doesnot work well in older version like IE8 and IE7.

So before the view is being render you can write an code to set the compatibility.

You can check it the link [JSF selectCheckBoxMenu not working properly in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220988/jsf-selectcheckboxmenu-not-working-properly-in-ie/19222333#19222333)

Comment: I went through your answer & all I have to say is, Primefaces is expected to make things cross browser compatible & that's why we use component libraries. If we need to need to tweak like this to make it work in IE then I think there is no good use of Primefaces & JSF.. any required tweaks should be made by jsf or PF themselves! but also I never heard PF people recommending such tweak to make it work in IE.. *(IE is not that unusual still!)*

Comment: They are working on it but we have good browsers like FF,Chrome etc IE still requires lot of improvement.